# Unable to download email attachment from gmail on live server on Heroku with imap-simple node module

Tags: node.js, express, gmail, imap

I tested downloading an attachment from Gmail on the localhost and it worked perfectly, but when I hosted on Heroku, it could not connect to the Gmail IMAP again. I would appreciate it if anyone who has experimented with this on Gmail on a live server could help me with a guide. I kept getting the response below

```
Trace: { Error: Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

My Imap setting is shown below:

```
let configure = (imapServerSettings) => {
   let config:ImapSimpleOptions = {
       imap: {
        user: imapServerSettings.username  as string,
        password: imapServerSettings.password  as string,
        host: imapServerSettings.host  as string,
        port: imapServerSettings.port as number,
        tls: imapServerSettings.tls as boolean,
        authTimeout:300000, // increased to 5 mins
        tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
}
}
    return config
};
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: You have been blocked by Gmail's security settings.  Use an Application Specific Password or OAuth.

Comment: @Max thanks. But I can still download attachment while on localhost but once on Heroku, I started getting the above error. Let me try an application-specific password, but the fact is that my applications connect to many IMAP servers other than Gmail. T

Comment: Exactly: google is going to block cloud providers by default since it's not a legitimate place for a user to read their emai (they're not running Thunderbird on heroku)l.  So you need to run through hoops to prove you're a good service.

Comment: @Max, To run through hoops is to use OAuth